# Html code inside jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html

how can I load HTML code in separated HTML file into dialog in another file.
when I click into anchor in one.html page, dialog appears containing HTML code exist in another HTML page.

I didn't make the code that appear in the dialog in the same page, because I will use this code into another places.

Comment: So, do you need to use ajax to load the external HTML?

Answer (score 1):

you can read your code using ajax

```
jQuery.get('second.html', function(html){
    $('#dialog').html(html).dialog();
})
```

This should work using jQuery and [jQuery UI for dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Hope this helps